# How can I modify a chart in ionic 2 to look like the picture below?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using import {Chart} from 'chart.js'; to create my chat but I have some challenges. I want to create a chart like the one shown below.

Best Regards

```
//Creating the doughth
    this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {


      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ["Cash in Hand", "Cash in Bank", "Cash in Mpesa"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [this.naaam, this.naaam1, this.naaam2 ],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            "#FF6384",
            "#36A2EB",
            "#FFCE56"
          ]
        }]
      }

    });
```

[image]

Comment: " but I have some challenges".. can you specify? are you talking about any error?

Comment: Not an error @suraj How can I put something in the middle like Total:91 and some animation where it can keep on changing.

Answer (score 0):

We're also using Chart.js in our Ionic 2 app. For rendering the charts we use the [ng2-charts](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts) library.

With regards to your question about putting the total in the bottom center, you can just wrap your chart in a div and add an absolutely positioned span element containing the total.

Comment: I am following this url:  https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-responsive-charts-graphs-to-ionic-2-applications/

Comment: Is ng2-charts quite different with what Josh has used here? https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-responsive-charts-graphs-to-ionic-2-applications/

Comment: I don't think it's that big of a difference. ng2-charts just provides some directives that you can add to your canvas element for easily binding the variables you set up in your typescript. 
In Josh's tutorial you bind the variables from typescript using nativeElement.

Comment: How can I achieve the above aspect using  Josh's example? Thanks